# Why is method with object parameter called instead of int parameter

Tags: c#

I don't understand this weird behavior. I have an overridden method that accepts int and a method that accepts an object type in derived class. If I pass an int, the method with object type is called.

```
using System;
public class Program
{
   static void Main(string[] args)
   {
      Derived d = new Derived();
      int i = 10;
      d.Func(i);
      Console.ReadKey();
  }
}
public class Base
{
  public virtual void Func(int x)
  {
      Console.WriteLine("Base.Func(int)");
  }
}
public class Derived : Base
{
  public override void Func(int x)
  {
      Console.WriteLine("Derived.Func(int)");
  }
  public void Func(object o)
  {
      Console.WriteLine("Derived.Func(object)");
  }
}
```

Why isn't the method that accepts int called?

https://www.ideone.com/OToXWS vs https://www.ideone.com/BIugxO

Comment: Have you had previous experience programming in Java?

Comment: No. I have never used Java.

Comment: Your exact question can be answered by [this article](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Overloading.aspx), looking to find a duplicate SO quetstion with it

Comment: As per that article compiler ignores your overridden method and calls Func with object.

Comment: This is a design decision, the purpose of which is to remove *some* problems, but it will introduce other problems, so it's a tradeoff. You will have to learn to live with it since I believe this is documented (though I'm not able to find that documentation right now).

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen  C# specification 5.0, section 7.5.3 (It is in the linked duplicate)

Comment: @ScottChamberlain Yup, I read that section and skipped the whole paragraph in search for something I seemed to remember, good find!