# Ignoring overridden function and using new function

Tags: c#, inheritance, overriding, overloading

Was just going through a quiz online for interview prep in `C#`. I read this problem:

```
using System;

// ...

public class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Derived d = new Derived();
        int i = 10;
        d.Func(i);
    }
}

public class Base
{
    public virtual void Func(int x)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Base.Func(int)");
    }
}

public class Derived : Base
{
    public override void Func(int x)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Derived.Func(int)");
    }

    public void Func(object o)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Derived.Func(object)");
    }
}
```

And it says that the output should actually be `Derived.Fun(Object)`. Can you help me to understand why it would do this? I thought it would call the `Func` command with the integer as the parameter.

Comment: My answer to a question like that would be "You shouldn't write code where it's not obvious what method will be called".

Comment: @juharr: to many people it would be immediately "obvious" that `Derived.Func(int)` should be called, as that's "clearly" a better match. The C# rules for overload resolution are the most complicated part of the spec, but I imagine not all developers know this -- until they come across a case like this.

Comment: Also asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52549449/why-is-method-with-object-parameter-called-instead-of-int-parameter) - dupe in and of itself

Comment: The real answer, "why", is in the bit about the "brittle base class problem" [here](https://csharpindepth.com/Articles/Overloading).